# 400 Error when using API with Android

Tags: android, rest, web-services, android-volley, http-status-code-400

I'm a beginner when it comes to using APIs in an Android application but I'm attempting to use Volley to access an API to gather geological data and for some reason, it keeps giving me an unexpected response 400 as shown below:

> E/Volley: [4123] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://mrdata.usgs.gov/mrds/search-bbox.php
>
> E/Rest Reponse: com.android.volley.ServerError

I understand that that error code is usually reserved for syntax errors but I can't find anything.  Below I have pasted my code:

```
private class MRData_Model extends Thread {
        RequestQueue requestQueue;
        JSONObject input;
        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest;

        public void run() {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

            try{
                //xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax are all doubles
                input = new JSONObject();
                input.put("xmin", xmin); 
                input.put("ymin", ymin); 
                input.put("xmax", xmax); 
                input.put("ymax", ymax);
                input.put("com", "CU");
                input.put("f", "JSON");
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("JSON Object Error", e.toString());
            }

            objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    url,
                    input,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.e("Rest Reponse", response.toString());
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("Rest Reponse", error.toString());
                        }
                    });

            requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
        }
    }
```

and the url I use is:
url = "https://mrdata.usgs.gov/mrds/search-bbox.php";

Below is also a screenshot of the documentation for this API:
[USGS MRData API Documentation for MRDS records within a geographic rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jthDP.png)

It's a pretty obscure API and I can't find anything about anyone using it so if anyone could help me, I would appreciate it very, very much.